# How can i use a button as a stacklayout in xamarin forms so i can customize it and work on the text position and image position?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I use a button as a stacklayout in xamarin forms so I can customize it and work on the text position and image position? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use stacklayout as button you can set text position and all in button as  there properties of horizontal options and vertical options in it

Comment: what i saw that was different are the border, you can use this property. [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderRadiusProperty/) So.. what is more different than this button that you want?

Comment: can i set 2 text lines 1 is fixed and the other is bindable ? 
and how to set the positions or padding ?

Comment: and i dont want a stack layout as a button but i want to freely set texts and images  positions just like a stacklayout that's what i mean

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can put a StackLayout inside a button, and put all your images and texts in that StackLayout. Or, in fact, you can use whatever panel you want

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek no i can't it tells me : Can not set the content of Button as it doesn't have a ContentPropertyAttribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Can place a gesture recognizer within the stack layout as if it were a button, for example:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
      <Image HeightRequest="35" Source="ButtonImage"/>
      <Label Text="ButtonText" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

             <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Button_Tapped"/>
             </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

</StackLayout>
```

The code behind would function like this:

```
void Button_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //Functionality Here
}
```

Comment: what about TabIndex and Focused event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom renderer to set the content for the button.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693721/xamarin-forms-content-of-a-button) answer. The created a custom control that is a button with content:

```
    public class ContentButton:ContentView
{
    private readonly TapGestureRecognizer _tapGestureRecognizer;

    public ContentButton()
    {
        _tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        GestureRecognizers.Add(_tapGestureRecognizer);          
    }

    protected override void OnChildAdded(Element child)
    {
        base.OnChildAdded(child);
        if (child is View childview)
        {
            childview.GestureRecognizers.Add(_tapGestureRecognizer);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ContentButton), null, BindingMode.Default, null, CommandPropertyChanged);

    private static void CommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue is ICommand command && bindable is ContentButton contentButton)
        {
            contentButton._tapGestureRecognizer.Command = command;              
        }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```